# how I create xaml if i already have cs without xaml

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, xaml

I already have class C#  `.cs`without `.xaml` page. Now I want to use `xaml` style in it. Can I create new `xaml` page and assign this with my written `.cs` class? Or I can delete my class and create new `xaml` with empty `cs`? I use Visual Studio 15  C#.

Comment: Can't you copy and paste the c# in the code for XAML after you have VS create it?

Comment: I just, I was interested in whether there is a way to add XAML not recreating class

Comment: Well, if the XAML has the same x:Class name as the class you're using and the class is marked as partial it should work.  I'm pretty sure the class also needs to inherit from at least DendencyObject but maybe further up the chain as UIElement.  I'll test this theory and let you know.

Comment: Thanks, currently I will know it

Comment: Yeap, all you need is to make the class partial.  Don't even need to inherit from anything else... but I probably would if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the x:class name the same as the class name.  Make sure they are in the same namespace or reference the same namespaces.

This code works and the XAML / Class was created separately of one another.

Might wanna add 'InitializeComponent();' to the class constructor also but this works as is.

```
<Page
x:Class="Class_with_XAML_seperate.TestView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Class_with_XAML_seperate"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

</Grid>
</Page>


using Windows.UI.Popups;

namespace Class_with_XAML_seperate
{
    public partial class TestView 
    {
        public TestView()
        {
            new MessageDialog("Hello World").ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```